# How to preserve the key letter case in AWS Glue Transform node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to add a new column called `timestamp` in AWS Glue.

My upstream data keys have capital letters.

[image]

However, after adding the column `timestamp`, the keys of the remaining columns got lowercased.

### Experiment 1: Transform - SQL Query

```sql
select 
    cast((Absolute_Time - 2082844800) * 1000 as bigint) as timestamp,
    *
from
    engine_demo;
```

However, it lowercases all my keys.

[image]

### Experiment 2: Transform - Custom code

```py
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
    
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    df = df.withColumn(
      "timestamp",
      ((F.col("Absolute_Time") - 2082844800) * 1000).cast("long")
    )
    dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "changed")
    return (DynamicFrameCollection({"result_dynf": dynamic_frame}, glueContext))
```

It also lowercases all my keys

[image]

### Experiment 3

I found [Enable case sensitivity for spark.sql globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946104/enable-case-sensitivity-for-spark-sql-globally)

However, there is no place to set in "Transform - SQL Query" node, so I try to set the config in "Transform - Custom" code:

```py
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    glueContext.spark_session.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
    
    df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    df = df.withColumn(
      "timestamp",
      ((F.col("Absolute_Time") - 2082844800) * 1000).cast("long")
    )
    dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "changed")
    return (DynamicFrameCollection({"dynamic_frame": dynamic_frame}, glueContext))
```

However, this above code gives same result.

Is there a way to preserve the key letter case in the AWS Glue Transform node? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my experiment result, if I remove this Transform "convert time" step and sink to Delta Lake directly. It will preserve the letter case.

However, as I am using Glue Crawler to register the Delta table in the Glue Catalog.

Here is some info I got from Jay Naves from AWS team (thanks!):

> Glue catalog forces lowercase column names to be Hive compatible
> because the Hive metastore schema lowercases all column names.
>
> https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/9d81764788920851c4461827a9984dbf48fdf6db/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java#L909

So even I preserved the case in Delta table. The downstream will still become lowercase.

I am ending up with this solution:

Since SQL query is designed to be case insensitive by default,

1.

```sql
select Absolute_Time from engine_demo;
```

will return `Absolute_Time`.

2.

```sql
select absolute_time from engine_demo;
```

will return `absolute_time`

3.

```sql
select * from engine_demo;
```

will return `absolute_time`.

Most time, in dashboard, users can query using first way to have correct letter case.

If any user needs to use `select *`, I can provide a dict to help map from lowercase to correct letter case.

Answer (score 0):

We can apply case sensitive flag in ApplyMapping section in the ETL job script. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897041/how-to-determine-what-are-the-columns-i-need-since-applymapping-isnt-case-sensi). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @SwathiP, however, this does not help my case. My upstream `Transform ApplyMapping` node has capital letters which has no issue which can be seen in first screenshot. My issue is at downstream which I have question now.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Have you tried "SelectFields" Transform? "SelectFields" Transform is case-sensitive as mentioned in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/transforms-configure-select-fields.html).

Comment: No problem! Well, `SelectFields` is for filtering columns. I am actually adding a new column.